# Windows registry

Tags: windows, browser, windows-7, registry, sublimetext

I did something wrong in Windows registry.

When I installed SublimeText editor - http://www.sublimetext.com/, I wanted to make all .html files open in it on double-click, not in browser.

It works now, but one unwanted feature added.

There are links to websites in some programms in Windows, such as Skype (in chat). When you click these links, default browser opens and shows you the site.

In my case, when I click these links, SublimeText opens with a blank tab named "http" or "https" o_O

How can I fix this?

Comment: Fix file associations: http://www.winvistaclub.com/t19.html

Comment: Those are seperate things, it sounds like the http protocol has become associated as well as the .html extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try "assoc"
cmd -> `help assoc`

Answer (score 0):

ChromeHTML > open > command > back to chrome.exe